Errors in .NET Maui template with no changes
Created a new .NET Maui app and without running it or making any changes it has four errors, they all say:
Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even through they have a specified platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst

How do I fix the template?

You have not downloaded .net 6 versions of MAUI probably which causes this issue

Have you tried updating the Visual Studio? What .NET version do you use?

Here is a similar thread on GitHub, No Maui Project Template and error: Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks. You may refer to this thread.
